# Binary of the latest Qt framework (with MingW32) working out-of-the-box for COM/ActiveX programming

Tags: qt, office-automation, qt4.8

Can someone point to me where I can find binary distribution of the latest Qt Framework 4.8.0. (with MingW32) ready for Office automation?

Comment: What does Qt have to do with Office automation?

Comment: @Lukáš Lalinský: As far as I know, Qt targets Windows platform and can do COM/ActiveX.

Comment: @Styne666: -1 for the question or for the comment? Please elaborate if it for the question. I have the feeling of being a collateral damage. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the question be then, where to download Qt? There is nothing Office-specific in Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinGW32 is not recommended if you want to do COM/ActiveX. Use VS2008 or VS2010.

[QAxObject](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qaxobject.html) is your friend.

Comment: Visual studio is not an option to me.

Comment: Why not? [It's free](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express). Why on earth would you develop ActiveX under MinGW32?

Comment: Visual studio is too bloated even the Express version.

Comment: +1: I end up installing VS2010 Express and accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/); you get MinGW separately, as well as any third-party component which integrates with Office.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have already Qt 4.8.0 (with MingW32) and Qt Creator 2.4.0 on my box. My wish is to make them truly COM/ActiveX capable or find a binary distribution working out of the box.

Comment: Qt [integrates with ActiveX](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt-activex.html) although you'll get no help from MS going the other way. Dunno what you mean by "truly", they're entirely separate technologies. You might as well say "truly bittorrent capable".